# Prometheus: Count the times a gauge's value has cahnged

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I would like to monitor the number of times values were set to a Prometheus Gauge per second.
Unfortunately, I cannot add another counter and should use the gauge.
I tried using [changes function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#changes) but either I did not understand its purpose or it simply did not do the job. Comparing the gauge graph to the changes() output with a verity of time ranges did not show any correlation.

Using [count_over_time](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) did not provide that metric, to my opinion, for the same reason as changes().

Is there a proper way of calculating the amount of times values were set to a Prometheus Gauge per second?

**Let's say that we have:**

prom_gauge = prometheus_client.Gauge("prom_gauge")

**And the following has happened:**

[12:00:00.0000] prom_gauge.set(10)

[12:00:00.3000] prom_gauge.set(30)

[12:00:00.5000] prom_gauge.set(20)

[12:00:01.0000] prom_gauge.set(5)

**The metric will provide the values:**

Value 3 for 12:00:00

Value 1 for 12:00:01

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, I cannot add another counter and should use the gauge.

A counter of some form is the only way to do it, there's no way to do this with a standard gauge.